# Powershell ConvertTo-json Output to lowercase

Tags: powershell

I am using below command to generate below output

```
$VMHost | ConvertTo-json | Out-File -encoding "UTF8" -FilePath  ".\$VMHostName.report"
```

But I need all the key in lowercase and values as it is like given below

```
 "HostNumaStatus": [
      {
         "ComputerName": "TEMSA10",
         "MemoryAvailable": 3119,
         "MemoryTotal": 6075,
         "NodeId": 0,
         "ProcessorsAvailability": "35 41 56 58"
      }
   ]
```

to

```
 "hostnumastatus": [
      {
         "computername": "TEMSA10",
         "memroyavailable": 3119,
         "memroytotal": 6075,
         "nodeid": 0,
         "processoravailability": "35 41 56 58"
      }
   ]
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use `[Regex]` static method `Replace`:

```
$Json = $VMHost | ConvertTo-Json

[regex]::Replace(
    $Json,
    '(?<=")(\w+)(?=":)',
    {
        $args[0].Groups[1].Value.ToLower()

    }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Drop this between the $VMHost and ConvertTo-JSON.

```
Select -Property @{N='computername';E={$_.ComputerName}}, @{N='memoryavailable';E={$_.MemoryAvailable}}, @{N='memorytotal';E={$_.MemoryTotal}}, @{N='nodeid';E={$_.NodeId}}, @{N='processorsavailability';E={$_.ProcessorsAvailability}}
```

Since the columns aren't static, try this:

```
$cols = $VMHost | select * | Get-Member | ForEach-Object {@{N=$_.Name.ToLower();E=$_.Name}}
$VMHost | Select -Property $cols | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File -encoding "UTF8" -FilePath  ".\$VMHostName.report"
```

I really wanted to get the object edited prior to the conversion, but this will get you the end result you're after:

```
# Get the JSON text
$JSON = $VMHost | ConvertTo-Json

# Loop through each line of the JSON output
$JSON.Split("`n") | ForEach-Object {
    # Split the line on the ":", grab the first portion, and trim the space
    $value = $_.Split(":")[0].Trim()
    # Check to see if both the start and end characters are quotes (these should be the key fields)
    if (($value.Substring(0,1) -eq "`"") -and ($value.Substring($value.Length-1,1) -eq "`"")) {
        # If it's a key make it lowercase
        $_.Replace($value,$value.ToLower())
        } else {
        # Otherwise leave it as-is
        $_
        }
    # Output
    } | Out-File -encoding "UTF8" -FilePath  ".\$VMHostName.report"
```

Comment: Thanks Tim for the answer but I need to convert whole output(only keys) into smallcase. This was just an extract from the outputted file.

Comment: I had a feeling that would be the case.

Comment: Try the second option.

Comment: Tim, it has worked for the parent object e.g. hostnumastatus but not for the child objects.   "hostnumastatus": [
      {
         "ComputerName": "TEMSA10",
         "MemoryAvailable": 3119,
         "MemoryTotal": 6075,
         "NodeId": 0,
         "ProcessorsAvailability": "35 41 56 58"
      }
   ]

Comment: +1 Because I take part of your solution using regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best solution but a crutch waiting for a better

```
# Get the JSON text
$JSON = $VMHost | ConvertTo-Json
$JSON.Split("`n") | % {if($_ -match "(.*):(.*)"){$_ -replace '(.*):(.*)',"$($matches[1].ToLower()):$($matches[2])"}else{$_}}
```

I use a regular expression to convert all the keys to lowercase, this must be tested with various JSONs

Perhaps someone can provide a better syntax.

Answer (score 0):

This worked well for me..hope this helps.

```
$data | ConvertTo-Json |Out-File "jsonfile.json"
(Get-Content -Path ".\jsonfile.json" -Raw).ToLower() |Out-File "jsonfile.json" -force -Encoding "UTF8"
```